# Have a 3rd field in cakePHP login

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.4

I have created many Authentication apps with CakePHP fairly easily. However, it's always the same: Username and Password.

I want to create a login for a user to select a company as well, and if authentication to that company fails, it returns back to the login page without having him logged on.

Reason for this is, we work in a 'Parent' company that has many children. All the administration for these children companies comes through the parent company. But now, since not all employees in the Parent company has access to all children companies, we need to check if, when they log into a certain company, they have access to that specific company. The trick is that it's a one to many relationship. One user, can have access to one company or 2 or 3 or all of them.

I have the basics of authentication down, thanks to the guide on the cakePHP site, but what would I need to change from here, to do the extra Authentication check?

Comment: Which version you are using cakephp 2.0?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, cakePHP 2.4

Comment: can't the user just be redirected to a random company of his (i.e. the first in alfabetical order) and after the login let the user switch between companies? You can do the redirect in your UsersController login action and then you  can create a switchCompany action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your own Authenticate component

you have to implement a function that checks if your user can log in and return an array of his data if so or false otherwise.

something like

\Controller\Component\Auth\CompanyAuthenticate.php

```
App::uses('FormAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class CompanyAuthenticate extends FormAuthenticate
{
    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response)
    {
        $user = parent::authenticate($request, $response);
        if(!$user) 
            return false;
        else
        {
             //check company
             // if company is ok return $user
             // else return false
        }
    }

}
```

Edit:

Of course you have to tell your application you are using this kind of authentication

So in your AppController you have to do:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array('Company'),
         // ... other options
        ),
    // ... other components you wish to load
);
```

Comment: This isn't working. I've added my function under `root/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/` but it's not running. I tested this by adding a `return false` in the `else`, but still nothing is happening.

Comment: Got it working. Had to change my `$components` array in my `AppController` where I set up my authentication. Also moved `CompanyAuthenticate.php` back to `APP/Controller/Component/Auth`. However, now I get a `Cannot call abstract method BaseAuthenticate::authenticate()` error...

Comment: yes, BaseAuthenticate is an abstract class, sorry. Try extend FormAuthenticate instead `App::uses('FormAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class CompanyAuthenticate extends FormAuthenticate`

Comment: awesome. That works. Thanks a lot. Easier than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

A note of caution using this method:

I inherited a CMS that did something like this.  It was set up with a company name, company password, username, and user password.  The one instance of the CMS would then administer many websites, choosing which one based on the credentials entered.

This turned out to be the most confusing mess for the users.  They would constantly call up trying to figure out their company username and company password.  This might have been OK back in the days of arbitrary usernames, but these days when most people use the email address as the username it's not required.

I can't see a valid reason for doing this at all, based on my experience.  If companies like google, paypal, facebook etc can figure it out with just a username and password, then I'm sure you'll be able to sort it out.

Just my $0.02, and as it looks like you're just starting the development for the system I hope you investigate other possibilities :-)

Comment: We've considered various approaches. Since all our companies run their emails through Google, it even gives me the option to use the Google login as a feature and just direct to a certain company from there. However, it makes it hard when a one email user needs access to 3 or 4 companies. We don't require a company password. The user will have one username and one password, but will be able to select a company based on a dropdown, so that solves the company username and password issue.